# Fill effect not working with special characters

Tags: html, css

the effect is working fine when it's one word with no spaces or special characters , when i add another word the effect snaps immediately .

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/abdulrhman-khalid/pen/zYRGEwM)

```css
/* Text-fill */

.text-fill {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 100px;
  font-weight: bolder;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: white;
  -webkit-text-stroke: 2px black;
  transition: 0.3s;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: fit-content;
}
.text-fill::before {
  content: attr(data-text);
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: cornflowerblue;
  width: 0%;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: 1s;
}

.text-fill:hover::before {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!-- text fill  -->
<p class="text-fill" data-text="WEB">WEB</p>
<p class="text-fill" data-text="Web Development">Web Development</p>
```

Comment: Post you code as a script not as an image, use the <> icon inside the editor to post a script.

Comment: The problem is that the before pseudo element content goes over 2 lines when its width is going from 0 to the full width so it fills up gradually as planned but it only manages to put the second word on the same line at the end so it 'jumps' into position.

Answer (score 0):

The code works fine, I didn't add anything. I may not have understood the question, but you may have forgotten to complete the `data-text` after completing the paragraph `<p>`

- An example with more text

```css
/* Text-fill */

.text-fill{
    position: relative;
    font-size: 100px;
    font-weight: bolder;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: white;
    -webkit-text-stroke: 2px black;
    transition: 0.3s;
    overflow: hidden;    
    width: fit-content;
}
.text-fill::before{
    content: attr(data-text);
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: cornflowerblue;
    width: 0%;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: 1s;
}

.text-fill:hover::before{
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!-- text fill  -->
<p class="text-fill" data-text="An example with more text">An example with more text</p>
<p class="text-fill" data-text="Another example with more text">Another example with more text</p>
```

The effect may be too slow for mobile devices.

- An example with characters, works as well as plain text.

```css
/* Text-fill */

.text-fill{
    position: relative;
    font-size: 100px;
    font-weight: bolder;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: white;
    -webkit-text-stroke: 2px black;
    transition: 0.3s;
    overflow: hidden;    
    width: fit-content;
}
.text-fill::before{
    content: attr(data-text);
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: cornflowerblue;
    width: 0%;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: 1s;
}

.text-fill:hover::before{
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!-- text fill  -->
<p class="text-fill" data-text="?±!@#$%^&*">?±!@#$%^&*</p>
<p class="text-fill" data-text="水山人口刀木日月女子馬鳥目">水山人口刀木日月女子馬鳥目</p>
```

In order for the effect not to be so slow, I recommend that you reduce the text so that it is not displayed in two lines.